# How to find a word after $number and before underscore or end of line?

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula

How do you find the `foobar` in lines such as:

```
something_something_$20_foobar
something_something_$20_foobar_something
something_something_something_$20_foobar_something
something_something_$1.5_foobar
something_something_$1.5_foobar_something
```

All you know for sure is that `foobar` will appear after an underscore followed by a number with dollar sign (integer or float) and after which will be either another underscore or the end of the line.

I've tried `\$.+_(.+)$` (which finds `foobar` in lines 1 and 4) and `\$.+_(.+)_` (which finds `foobar` in lines 2, 3 and 5).

So you'd think `\$.+_(.+)[$_]` or `\$.+_(.+)($|_)` would find it in all lines, but they both find it only in some lines and find the wrong word in others.

Comment: use `(.+?)` otherwise .* will match everything until the end of line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?_([^_\n]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4B3Ot4/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\$`: Match a `$`
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?`: Match optional part after decimal point
- `_`: Match a `_`
- `([^_\n]+)`: Capture group #1 to match 1+ of any character that is not `_` and not a line break

Comment: Since it doesn't check for a $ sign, while it works for all given examples, it fails in others (as mentioned all that's known is what will be immediately before and after `foobar`). For example, due to 1234 in `something_1234_something_$20_foobar`.

Comment: Though `$` wasn't part of your requirements but if it is there then use: `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?_([^_\n]+)`

Comment: Thanks! (it was mentioned in the title plus in various test code examples, but you're right it should have been mentioned better, so I've rephrased now to mention it literally and directly.

Comment: Yes, thanks! But I'm conflicted as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75726391/4829915) worked too (even directly as just regex), so not sure which answer to mark as accepted...

Comment: I guess, whichever solution you find it easier to implement and more efficient in your real sheet just select it.

Comment: You offer 1 regex, they offer another (it's not needed to use theirs like an array formula). Both regex work equally in Google Sheets...

Comment: My answer is pure regex solution as you had stated earlier before tagging with google-sheet. This regex will work same in any other tool/language whereas other answer is a specific google-sheet solution.

Comment: It's only because they ignored my comment that it can also work as pure regex. I've edited it to reflect it, but someone needs to approve the edit. In other words, the regex they mentioned inside their command can also be used standalone like yours.

Comment: `\$\d*\.?\d*?_(.*?)(?:_|$)` is a lot inefficient than the regex I have it here. If you paste it in the regex101 demo I have provided, step count moves from 49 to 182.

Comment: Your comment is very interesting. You got the approved answer now. Any idea why such a major difference in steps?

Comment: It is different due to use of `.*?` which is inefficient as compared to `[^_\n]+` (a negated character class that prevent any backtracking)

Answer (score 1):

Within sheets to apply the regex across the range as an `arrayformula` style use:

```
=map(A:A,lambda(z,regexextract(z,if(z="",,"\$\d*\.?\d*?_(.*?)(?:_|$)"))))
```

OR for a stand-alone cell you could directly go with:

```
=regexextract(A1,"\$\d*\.?\d*?_(.*?)(?:_|$)")
```

[image]

Comment: `Unknown function: 'TOCOL'.` -  is there any chance it's an app script you use? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNoZS.png

Comment: you can try: `=map(A:A,lambda(z,regexextract(z,if(z="",,"\d_(.*?)(?:_|$)"))))`

Comment: `tocol` is a [new function](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/200022527?hl=en); most likely it is yet to roll out fully for ya...

Comment: The alternative is supported but since it doesn't check for a $ sign, it fails with variants that have numbers like because of the 1234 in `something_something_1234_something_$20_foobar`.

Comment: Can you try the updated answer

Comment: It works better, but it expects 2 digits, $20 was just an example, it can also be $2 and then it will fail.

Comment: try: `=map(A:A,lambda(z,regexextract(z,if(z="",,"\$\d*\.?\d*?_(.*?)(?:_|$)"))))`

Comment: Nice! Interestingly it brings exact results to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75726194/4829915 even though the regex is different. BTW, it can also be used directly per row with as ``\$\d*\.?\d*?_(.*?)(?:_|$)``.

Comment: Maybe update the answer with the final suggestion (and possibly mention it can be used directly too)?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\d_)[a-z]+' file
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
foobar
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Regex | description |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=\d_)` | PositiveLookBehind: matches the regex only if it is preceded by a single digit followed by `_` |
| `[a-z]+` | Matches one or more lowercase letters |

##### **[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI4To2/1)**

Comment: I know I wrote it's a general question, but any chance not to use \K which isn't supported in Google Sheets?

Comment: Yes, use `(?<=\d_)[a-z]+`

Comment: Not supported either.

Comment: Next time, add the proper `google-sheet` tag as I've done

Comment: I apologize. I've changed to an even more specific tag of sheet formulas.